# pulsectl library - Could not find module 'libpulse.so.0'

Tags: python-3.x, pulseaudio, pulse

I made a python script on linux, which uses the `pulsectl` library and it works just fine. When I tried to run it on windows i got an error: `FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libpulse.so.0' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.`. I have pulsectl installed on both systems. I searched for the file on multiple sites, but I couldn't find anything. Not even a single thread about this error. Here is the traceback message: https://pastebin.pl/view/17da8815

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. If anybody has the same problem, go to [this site](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Ports/Windows/Support/), download the preview binaries, extract items, open the `bin` folder and then copy all the items to your C:\Windows folder. If asked for permission from UAC just click 'Allow'. And that's it.